# Splunk: How to get specific timestamps if there are multiple in one event and change format and timeszones to compute timediff within one event?

Tags: splunk

I have such events:

```
something
<operation>abc</operation>
<timeSent>2022-01-22T02:55:58.002Z</timeSent>
<operation>def</operation>
<timeSent>2022-01-21T13:09:18.333Z</timeSent>
```

What I now want to get is the timestamp of every event and the last timestamp (i. e. the maximum timestamp of the `timeSent`-timestamps).

I tried this:

```
rex field=_raw "timeSent>(?<timeSent>[T:0-9-.]+)Z<" 
| stats max(_time) as Responsetime, min(timeSent) as Requesttime
```

But this only gives me the maximum timestamp of all of the observed timestamps and the minimum of all `timeSent`-timestamps. Moreover, I have the problem that I have on the one hand a different format for the timestamps and also different timezones. How could I solve this in order to compute the difference of `Responsetime` and `Requesttime`?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps have to be converted into epoch (integer) form before they can be compared.  Do that with the `strptime()` function.

```
rex field=_raw "timeSent>(?<timeSent>[T:0-9-.]+)Z<" 
| eval timeSent = strptime(timeSent, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%Z")
| stats max(_time) as Responsetime, min(timeSent) as Requesttime
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I still get the maximum `_time` of the whole timeframe I am examining. And now, I do not get any result for the Reqeusttime anymore. Instead I wanted to get the _time for each event and the min(ResponseTime) for each event.

Comment: `stats` is an aggregation command, meaning individual events are lost.  You can add a `by` clause to `stats` to group the aggregations by some other field(s), but you still will not have data for each event.

Comment: Is it possible to get the results how I would like to get them?

Comment: I know of no way to combine events (to their time difference) and keep them separate.

Comment: Ok, but actually I think I do not have to combine several events but look for `_time` of the event and within this event find the `min(timeSent)` and get the difference of `_time` and `min(timeSent)` within this event. I do not know if I asked my question really well, sorry!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this may help.  `| eval timeSent = strptime(timeSent, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%Z")
| eventstats min(timeSent) as Requesttime | eval diff=_time - Requesttime`

Comment: No, this helps, thank you! However, I am still not there. :-D